# VB.NET Trim does not work on XML InnerText that contains a vbLf?

Tags: xml, vb.net

If I take the following XML:

```
<security>
<user>user</user>
<password>pass   </password>
</security>
```

and call the `Trim()` method on the `InnerText` of the password node, it Trims it properly, but If I modify the fragment to look like this:

```
<security>
<user>user</user>
<password>pass
```

I can't get the `Trim()` method to work, pass with the spaces removed is return as `pass` (It has a single space at the end).  I looked at the watch window and when I doubnle click the value, it shows it as:

`"pass" & vbLf & ""`

Comment: It has a line feed at the end? that's why you see the space, or I'm missing something on your question?

Comment: I am not adding this line feed in code, it only occurs if the xml if formatted that way in the document.  Is there a way I can remove the line feed and why when I call Trim() does it not do it, I thought that was the purpose of Trim()

Comment: Trim removes spaces.. a line feed is not a space... you see like a space, but really is not..

Comment: What about the poor user whose password is 5 spaces? :P

Comment: @gbianchi - I see it now, but it is very misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String.Trim method never removes new line characters.  It only removes spaces.  If you want to remove all line feeds, you could simply do something like this:

```
InnterText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Trim()
```

But, that will remove any line feeds at the beginning or in the middle of the text.  But, perhaps that is what you want, anyway.

Or, you can use Trim's overload to pass an array of characters to remove (but it will only remove from the beginning and end, not the middle):

```
InnterText.Trim(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).Trim()
```

Comment: More idiomatic answer: `String.Trim` has an overload that takes `Char()`. OP could pass `NewLine` as one of these and achieve the desired result.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted in this case.  I actually only noticed the new line when I double clicked the value field in the watch window, so it was very misleading at first when I kept seeing "pass "

Comment: @Tom W, NewLine, at least on windows in English is actually two characters, so to send it to trim, you'd have to first convert it to a byte array, but you make a good point.

Comment: @TomW - Can you provide an example of how I would use the overloaded Trim inline instead of declaring an array of characters to remove first.

Comment: The big question here is how the hell the user inserted a new line char as his pass?? I would check other part of the code too...

Comment: @Xaisoft, I updated my answer to show how to use the Trim overload.

Comment: @SteveDog - Thanks, I Saw it, it works great.  This will remove the white space as well, right, not just line feeds?

Comment: That will remove all spaces, and new line characters from the beginning and end of the text.  It will not remove tabs or any other whitespace characters.  If you need to do that, I would suggest building an array of all the characters you want to remove, and reuse that array every time you call Trim.

Comment: @SteveDog: Thanks for pointing out the 'deliberate' mistake. Worth nothing that your modified method will remove carriage returns, newlines, AND Environment.NewLine since either of the two companion characters could also appear on their own.

Comment: @TomW, true.  I should have been more clear.  When I said "new line characters", I meant, any individual character that is used in the Environment.NewLine string--whatever they happen to be :)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, according to the page for [Char.IsWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), line feeds, tabs, and carriage returns are all whitespace characters. It also has the caveat that this function returning true does not mean that it will be removed by Trim.

You can either use Replace or pass a [Char array to Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to characters you want to remove.

Comment: Because they are white space to the user view. But trim doesn't care about user view, it care about chars view, so for trim, they are not white space.